# Trying to get Row function work with arrays

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula, row

I am trying to create an array out of an array to be later used in finding maximum consecutive values.
Formula is `=IF(ARRAY_1="A",ROW(ARRAY_1))`
This is meant to create array with location/row number from ARRAY_1 wherever there is value "A" or give the result False everywhere else. Normally this works fine if ARRAY_1 is a range, but I am trying a dynamic array here and instead of giving location/row number where the result is true, the function is giving #VALUE error.

Can you please suggest some other function to get the required result or to modify the one so that it can work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try `SEQUENCE`:

```
=LET(f,FILTER(A1:A6,A1:A6=A1:A6),
IF(f="a",SEQUENCE(ROWS(f))))
```

`f` represents the dynamic array (in this case it doesn't make sense but is used to test the function).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach, you could try using <kbd>TOCOL()</kbd> with <kbd>SEQUENCE()</kbd> function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=LET(α,TOCOL(A:A,1),IF(α="a",SEQUENCE(ROWS(α))))
```

---

Although as per your OP since you have an array it will be like this:

```
=IF(A1#="a",SEQUENCE(ROWS(A1#)))
```

---

Where it is assumed `A1#` is an array!

Comment: Great....this solution works perfectly.